# How to make ack stop after the first match?

Tags: grep, ack

I am trying to look for patterns in a file. The looks like this:

```
aaa;
bbb;
```

If I try the following it does not stop:

```
cat test | tr -d '\n' | ack -1 'aa.*;'
aaa;bbb;
```

Is there a way to stop with `aaa;`?

Comment: Please add your desired output for that sample input to your question.

Comment: It is added, maybe you need more highlighting?

Comment: Thanks, I missed that.

Comment: This might help: `head -n 1 test`

Comment: The pattern that I am looking for is not in the first position. It can be in the middle of the file. ACK does not support multi-line pattern matching and it was suggested on other SO answers that removing the new line from the file is the only way to look for patterns that can span over multiple lines.

Comment: You've deleted all linefeeds, so your file is now one line, surely? So if you are expecting it to stop at the next line, that will be the end of file.

Answer (score 1):

Your regex is *greedy*, so it includes all text after the second `a` until the final semi-colon. If you refine the pattern to NOT be greedy (with a question mark) and use the -o option, you'll get what you expect:

```
$cat test.txt | tr -d '\n' | ack -o 'aa.*?;' 
aaa;
```

See more recipes/details [here](https://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/perl/cookbook/ch06_16.htm)

Answer (score 0):

This is doing the trick:

```
 ack -1 -io 'a[^;]+;'
```